# Elegant alternative to looping over the same data?

Tags: c++

Got a bit of a dilemma.

```
std::map<myClass, int>                  myMap;


void Distribute(){
    float pool = 50;
    int receivers = 0;
    for(auto i = myMap.begin(); i != myMap.end(); i++){
        if(i->second == 1) receivers++;
    }

    float distribution = pool/receivers;

    for(auto i = myMap.begin(); i!= myMap.end; i++){
        if(i->second == 0)continue;
        i->first.value = distribution;
    }
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is find the total size of the map, minus the elements with mapped values of 0. After that, I want to loop over the same map again, but send values to each entry using the data I collected from the last for loop.

This feels really ugly and inefficient. Surely there has to be some way of handling it all in 1 for loop? Or maybe the first for loop ideally wouldn't be necessary? I'm not against extra work, but I can't help feeling I'm writing ugly code here, I'd really like some input.

Comment: You could keep a second map that only contains entries for the non-zero items, and update it as necessary whenever you modify the first map.  Then your count-the-nonzero-receivers function reduces down to just a nice O(1) call to ‘theSecondMap.size()’ (at the cost of making updates to the first map a bit more complex and expensive, of course)

Comment: I might not understand it correctly but.. why can't you just: use `i->first.value = distribution;` in the first loop in the same if-statement?

Comment: multiple independent loops is still O(n). it's basically just as efficient. It's probably got slightly more overhead but unless you're working on some weak hardware it shouldn't matter. What you wanna worry about are nested loops.

Comment: Real-world performance is not as simple as big-O notation, @Chris. The coefficients of n matter a lot. Sure, O(n^2) is far worse, but I've gotten overall speed-ups of two or three times by merging two independent loops. More than doubling the performance is certainly enough to matter to me, and I don't call it "just as efficient". It's only just as efficient in a theoretical sense. The weakness of the hardware is also not relevant. In particular, multiple independent loops are harder to vectorize, so the performance difference is probably even worse on advanced hardware.

Comment: Not much way around it here, I'm afraid, @Gavyn. There are alternative ways of *writing* the code, but somewhere, you'll still need to loop twice. For example, in modern C++, you have things like [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), which hide the loop from you and allow you to program in a more functional style, but the loop is still happening, and you're still paying the performance costs, even though they may be minor. Is there a way you can change your design/algorithm?

Comment: @CodyGray You're not doubling the performance by putting everything into one loop. Splitting the same number of operations into two loops doesn't change how many total operations are required to do your task.

Comment: @ChrisRollins doubt it matters here, but on modern computers, overall performance is often bounded by CPU-cache performance, which is in turn determined by locality-of-reference.  In that scenario (and when the contents of the map are large enough that they won't fully fit in the CPU's cache), it will be significantly faster to only iterate the loop once as compared to twice, since two iterations will mean ~twice the amount of RAM that has to be pulled in to cache.

Comment: @Gavyn what if you update your distribution value only when you add/remove/update values in the map? Then you don't have to loop over it to update that value every time you need it.

Answer (score 2):

if your data is inserted by yourself, you can use a wrapper class contains your map

```
class Wrapper{
public:
  int receivers = 0;
  std::map<myClass, int> myMap;// be sure you have operator< for myClass
  void insert(pair<myClass, int> item){
    myMap.insert(item);
    // count receivers when you insert , get receivers in constant time
    if(item.second == 1){
      receivers++;
    }
  }
};

void Distribute(){
  float pool = 50;
  Wrapper wrapper;
//insert your items by wrapper.insert(..) , not wrapper.myMap.insert(..)
  float distribution = pool/wrapper.receivers;
  for(auto& [i, j]: wrapper.myMap){
    if(j == 1){
      i.value = distribution;// be sure value is a public member of myClass
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach but I'd suggest making the `myMap` (and `receivers`) variables private, otherwise outside callers might add/remove/change items inside `myMap` without updating `receivers` properly.

Comment: Updating the receivers variable as the map is updated! That'd work well in this case. Thank you, I really appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is single-threaded.

You have to do the loop twice, but you can store the addresses of the elements that need to be changed so you don't have to test twice.

Note there is a very ugly const_cast in this code. It is ugly for a reason. You don't want to change the key of a map; it can break the map's behavior. I suspect you can simplify and improve your design by taking the second element (the 0 or 1 indicator) and making it a *field* in myClass. Then you don't need a map, just a set, vector, or list of myClass.

I also had to define a hash and operator== for myClass. I've omitted that part to show the important section.

```
void Distribute(){
    float pool = 50;
    std::vector<myClass*> nonzeros;
    for (auto iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); ++iter) {
        if (iter->second == 1) { nonzeros.push_back(const_cast<myClass *>(&(iter->first))); }
    }
    if (nonzeros.empty()) return;
    const float distribution = pool/nonzeros.size();
    std::for_each(nonzeros.begin(), nonzeros.end(),
        [distribution](decltype(nonzeros)::value_type pClass) {pClass->value = distribution;});
}
```